# segmentation fault C finite state machine

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, switch-statement, fault, fsm

I am relatively new to C programming and I am trying to make a delimiter checker, but for some reason every time I run my code and it gets my input to check for delimiters, it has a *segmentation fault (core dumped)* error.

Below is the code of the main program:

```
int
main (void)
{
  char* mystring;
  printf ("Please enter a string\n");
  gets(mystring);
  if (fsm(mystring))
    {
      printf ("All matched");
    }
}
```

It seems like it never enters the subprogram `fsm` though, because I put in a `printf` right at the beginning of the subprogram and it never shows up.  It does ask for my input though and prints it back out if I put the `printf` in the main program before the subprogram line.

Here is my prototype:

```
boolean fsm(char[]);
```

and here is the beginning of the subprogram if that is any help:

```
boolean fsm (char mystring[])
{
  printf("here\n");
  int counter = -1;
  int state = 0;
  c_stack top;
  c_init_stack (&top);
  while (1)
    {
      switch (state)
    {
    case 0:
      counter = counter + 1;
      if (is_open (*mystring))
        state = 1;
      else if (is_close (*mystring))
        state = 2;
      else if (mystring = '\0')
        state = 3;
      else
        state = 4;
      break;
```

Comment: 1) `else if (mystring == '\0')` (I guess the function argument points to a string-literal?) 2) `char* mystring;
  printf ("Please enter a string\n");
  gets(mystring);
` mystring points to nowhere. 3) don't use gets()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to read into an uninitialized `char*`. Just declaring `char *mystring` doesn't give you a string to work with: you'll need to allocate space for the string.

Either:

```
char *mystring = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
```

Or:

```
char mystring[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
```

Once you have a buffer, use `fgets` instead of `gets`. `fgets` allows you to specify an upper-bound on the number of characters read, so `fgets` along with something like `MAX_STRING_LEN` you'll be able to accept only as much data as your buffer will hold.

As it is, since C doesn't initialize automatic (local) variables, `mystring` has an undefined value. It can point to any random part of memory. When you try to `gets` using this memory location, you're trying to write to that memory that doesn't belong to you.

Finally, this condition with a single `=`: `else if (mystring = '\0')` is an assignment, and not an equality test.